# Deploy a kubernetes Pod using golang code

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a possibility to deploy a **kubernetes Pod** using **golang** code instead of command line Linux with **kubectl** ?

Comment: It's fairly prominent in the Kubernetes documentation; https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#api-client-libraries

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Definitely you can. Kubernetes is written in golang. It has official client for go. You can create,delete,patch,list, control almost any Kubernetes resources with this go client.

Here is the official client repository: [kubernetes/client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go)

I have create a sample repository [here](https://github.com/hossainemruz/k8s-client-go-practice) to show how to create a pod using `client-go`.

You have to do following things to create a pod with this client. We are going to create a simple busybox pod.

1. Create `configuration` using your kube-config file. Generally the configuration file is `$HOME/.kube/config` file. See example [here](https://github.com/hossainemruz/k8s-client-go-practice/blob/56eeb12f1ce54d3fe4d428e7546d70cd5bde3b50/main.go#L26).
2. Create a `clientset` using this `configuration`. See example [here](https://github.com/hossainemruz/k8s-client-go-practice/blob/56eeb12f1ce54d3fe4d428e7546d70cd5bde3b50/main.go#L31).
3. Now, generate a pod definition that we want to deploy. See example [here](https://github.com/hossainemruz/k8s-client-go-practice/blob/56eeb12f1ce54d3fe4d428e7546d70cd5bde3b50/main.go#L37).
4. Finally, create the pod in kubernetes cluster using the `clientset`. See example [here](https://github.com/hossainemruz/k8s-client-go-practice/blob/56eeb12f1ce54d3fe4d428e7546d70cd5bde3b50/main.go#L40).

Answer (score -3):

You can write a function and give the cell image yaml file as a parameter.

```
func cellDeploy(pathToFileName string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command("kubectl", "apply", "-f", pathToFileName)
    stdoutReader, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stdoutScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdoutReader)
    go func() {
        for stdoutScanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(stdoutScanner.Text())
        }
    }()
    stderrReader, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()
    stderrScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stderrReader)
    go func() {
        for stderrScanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(stderrScanner.Text())
        }
    }()
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error : %v \n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v \n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: This is still just simply using golang to call kubectl.